# register globals php

Tags: php

I know register globals should not be used but cannot quite understand why?

For example: this is the code that I find so often to demonstrate the security risk of using register globals while passing something like `example.com?authorized=1` to the script:

```
if (authenticated_user()) 
{ 
$authorized = true; 
} 

if ($authorized) 
{ 
include '/highly/sensitive/data.php'; 
}
```

My question is if the user has to pass `authorized=1` in the url he should be aware of the variable names that i use in my script, right? How is that possible?

Also isn't a function like `parse_str()` which behaves somewhat similar to register globals a security risk too?

Comment: One of the reasons of not using it can be "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0." as per PHP Manual

Comment: Even if the possible hacker doesn't know the exact variable names used in the script, anything in the query string can pose a **possible** security risk.

Comment: IMHO, `parse_str` will be safe if the input string is either hard-coded or from trusted sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The attacker may have access to your source code via another security hole or privacy breach.
2. The attacker can guess. It's pretty trivial to build a bot to enumerate all the plausible variables names and try them against thousands of php sites. (`?authorized=1`, `?login=1`, `?access=1`, etc.)

**EDIT**

In response to `parse_str`, it depends what exactly the use case is, but in general probably.
If `parse_str` is passed any user provided content, then yes, absolutely it's unsafe.

There may be some legitimate use cases for it where the input provided is not user-provided, but in general I'd stay away from it.

I would also say the same about `extract`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2):

Just think why you used `authorized` to name your variable?  To make is descriptive right? **hackers uses dictionary words** in url and such descriptive variable are then get set if `register_globals` are on

Comment: I'm not sure how MD5 hash generation is related to this kind of vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that the hacker would need to know the variable names, in many cases these can be easy to guess and a trivial task to attempt to brute force.

This becomes even more true when you are using open source software, plugins or copy/pasting popular code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `register_globals` is a security risk.

- It is turned on at a PHP level so you cannot say that it is safe to turn on citing only one script.
- The programmer (could be any programmer not just you) will not be aware how `$authorized` is being set and may inadvertantly leave security loop holes within the code.
- Variables registered with `register_globals` are `superglobals` meaning they are available across any scope within the PHP script.

Next we look at `parse_str`. This function only parses variables into the **current scope** of the code ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)). Any programmer can look at the current scope and determine if and how they want to secure it. It is still not very secure but it is not as insecure as `register_globals`.